# Scheduling Mechanism in Linux Kernel 3.0+

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler

Which Scheduling Mechanism is used with Linux Kernel (3.0+) by default, I guess Premptive Scheduling ?

Can we select some other mechanism like Deadline First or Round Robin while building (from the menuconfig) ? 
And In Round-Robin Mechanism, how time slice is allocated and used in Kernel ? (I mean Is the time slice calculated on run-time ?)

Answer (score 5):

Linux is currently using the CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) scheduler. You can read about it in the [kernel documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt). It also contains a real-time scheduler which is disabled by default.

For a very short summary, CFS maintains a time-ordered red-black tree, where all runnable tasks are sorted by the amount of work the CPU has already performed (accounting for wrap-arounds). CFS picks the task with the least amount of work done and "sticks to it". More details are available in the documentation.